# I can't add an Image to a canvas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I looked at a bunch of other questions on how to add Images to a canvas object in Javascript and I can't seem to get it to work for me. What I have is an array of objects which hold the location and dimension of a bunch of tiles, this is so I can reference the tiles latter, which makes it very complicated to apply and my code is a bit of a mess from me trying to fix it. Here is the full code.

```js
<script>
    var boardHieght = 6;
    var boardLength = 15;
    var board = new Array(boardLength);  
    var empty="BlankSquare.bmp";

    for (i = 0; i < boardHieght; i++) {
        board[i] = new Array(boardLength);
    }
    function createBoard() {
        createArray();
        myGameArea.start();
        
    }
    
    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 1000;
            this.canvas.height = 500;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        }
    }
    function createArray(){
        for(i=0; i<boardHieght; i++){
            for(j=0; j<boardLength; j++){
                board[i][j]= new tile(50*i, 50*j, 50, 50 , "BlankSquare.bmp");
            }
        }
    }
    function tile(x, y, height, length, contents){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.height=height;
        this.length=length;
        this.contents=contents;
    }
    function buildBoard(){
        for(i=0; i<boardHieght; i++){
            for(j=0; j<boardLength; j++){
                var x=board[i][j].x;
                var y=board[i][j].y;
                var height=board[i][j].height; 
                var length=board[i][j].length;
                var contents=board[i][j].contents;
                var curretnTile= new printTile(x, y, height, length, contents);
                curretnTile.update();
            }
        }
    }
    function printTile(x, y, height, length, cnt){
        this.cnt=cnt;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.height=height;
        this.length=length;
        var image = new Image();
        image.src=cnt
        this.update = function() {
            ctx=myGameArea.context;
            ctx.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y, this.length, this.height);         
        }
    }
    
    function updateGameArea(){
        buildBoard();
    }
    
    
</script>
```

I looked at a bunch of other questions and it seems the problem is loading the image before adding it to the canvas. I can't work out how to implement it in this case.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image url to an `img` element `src` attribute, and then using that image for your canvas?

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant, but I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by changing the image in prinTile from var to this.